# Why is curl working on my Meteor site but Google cannot seem to crawl my site?

Tags: curl, meteor, seo, phantomjs, meteor-up

I've just deployed a website using Meteor Up and I'm trying to figure out whether my site is crawlable by Google.

When I execute

> curl www.compmaker.com?_escaped_fragment_=

it returns the page with all the text. Also, when I do a search for "compmaker.com" as the search query, it seems to list my site with some content in the description.

However, in Google Webmaster, when I go to Fetch As Google, and press Fetch and Render, the content is missing in the  of the HTML. In addition, Adsense rejected my site as it couldn't see any text on it.

So I'm wondering, is spiderable actually working? If not, why is it that when I use curl I can actually see the html but google isn't able to?

In addition, if I install through Meteor Up and I have "setupPhantom" set up true, and I have spiderable as a package in my meteor project, what else do I need to get google to crawl my Meteor site?

I have a feeling that maybe phantomjs might've worked at the start, and then at some point, stopped working (the site's google cached copy is a couple of days ago) and curl is working because I've got fast-render on. Is that a plausible explanation and if so, how do I get phantomjs restarted again?

Comment: In which folder is your routes.js file?

Comment: @CaptSaltyJack - it's in lib, accessible to both server and client (necessary for Fast Render). Why? How would that be related to this?

Comment: Client-side routes are not spiderable as far as I'm aware.

Answer (score 0):

The most common issue that's producing symptoms similar to what you describe is that we (Google) can't reach resources critical for rendering.

In Fetch and Render you can see at the bottom of the page which resources failed to load during rendering. If there are some shown there, I would work fixing those: make sure the server responds quickly to those resource requests, and they're not blocked by robots.txt.

Answer (score 0):

I am having a somewhat similar issue as what you describe and you can see detailed info here http://www.themastfarminn.com/php-prob/

I sent in a support ticket to hosting company and here is what they replied:

|||||||||||||||||||||||||||

We recently updated our Mod Security settings for all signature accounts. This will block any requests that do not include the user-agent string in the HTTP header and send a forbidden response. To fix the problem you will need to update your script (curl script) to include a user-agent string and the server will then allow the connection.

|||||||||||||||||||||||||||